# Characters appended to a string all appear as question marks in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have been using the same code to get the fullname from the current user for a while now and it suddenly started behaving weird.
I have a string variable named CurrentUser which I populate with my function GetFullNameOfLoggedUser().
This return in the immediate window (msgbox also works fine) "Lastname, Firstname (F)" which it is supposed to.

When I want to give the variable to another string variable called 'sql1', it starts to behave weird all of a sudden:

```
CurrentUser = GetFullNameOfLoggedUser()
Dim sql1 As String: sql1 = "UPDATE Tbl_Records SET Tbl_Records.[Added by] = """ & CurrentUser & """ WHERE Tbl_Records.[Added by] IS NULL;"
```

The value of sql1 suddenly becomes:

```
UPDATE Tbl_Records SET Tbl_Records.[Added by] = "Lastname, Firstname (F)? ????? ?????????????????? ??? ?? ?????
```

Does anybody have a clue where all the question marks come from?

**Disclaimer** Lastname and Firstname are obviously regular values, they are omitted for the sake of privacy.

**Extra info:**

To get the full network name, I am using this fine piece of code from Dev Ashish which makes use of windows API:
http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0066.htm

The function has been dimmed as string. I have added an "" at the end of the function to ensure the value is a string type:

```
Function GetFullNameOfLoggedUser(Optional strUserName As String) As String
...
GetFullNameOfLoggedUser = StrFromPtrW(pTmp.EUI_full_name) & ""
End Function
```

[image]

As seen in the locals window, it truly is a string. (This snap has been taken right before the end of the funcion, so no further changes will happen to the variable.

CurrentUser has also explicitly been defined as a string variable. Option Explicit is also active on every page.

Comment: is (F) part of the name or is that strange too? also is this the case with all names ?

Comment: (F) belongs to the "CurrentUser" as well. (First letter of the first name) I have not been able to try it on different computers. But the name I am using right now has never given me this problem before.

Comment: Check both the type of the `CurrentUser` variable and the return type of the `GetFullNameOfLoggedUser()` function. Declare them explicititly to be `String`. If one of those is `Variant`, weird things can happen. Also, debug the `GetFullNameOfLoggedUser()` function, and check where it is getting its result, and if any other operation in the app is modifying this value (maybe add a Watch to the variable).

Comment: I have added some extra info, and that's the part that confuses me. Everything goes exactly as I would expect, except inputting a regular string variable into another regular string variable. Thanks for the responses so far. I will add a watch and get back with hopefully some more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There does seem to be something a bit strange about the string that `fGetFullNameOfLoggedUser()` returns. When I run the code

```vbs
Dim s As String
s = fGetFullNameOfLoggedUser()
Debug.Print Len(s)
Debug.Print s
```

I get

```
 13
GORD THOMPSON
```

which looks correct. However, if I change the last `Debug.Print` to

```vbs
Debug.Print "|" & s & "|"
```

I get

```
|GORD THOMPSON?
```

with the final character being a question mark `?` instead of a pipe `|`. However, if I `Trim()` the string

```vbs
Debug.Print "|" & Trim(s) & "|"
```

then I get

```
|GORD THOMPSON|
```

Comment: You, sir Gord Thompson, are my hero. It solved the problem completely. I am however curious as to what caused this abnormality! Somehow, the string causes all the following characters to change to questionmarks!

Comment: @JenZzz My guess is that the string has a trailing null (`Chr(0)`) that is ignored by `Len()` and does not print on its own. However, appending characters after it makes the string look like Unicode, which the VBA environment can only display as question marks.

Comment: How strange. Anyway, thanks for the answer and clear explanation!